# In case i would like to read back a long vector the way i would if creating one so that i can make adjustments, how can i do that using R?

Tags: r, vector

For example I create a long vector say

```
Vector<-c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","15")
```

I see that it created it but when I want to view it i can't just click and see it like this

```
c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","15"
```

or

```
"col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col10","col11","col12","15"
```

instead it looks like this

```
[1] "col1" "col2" "col3"
[4] "col4" "col5" "col6"
[7] "col7" "col8" "col9"
[10] "col10" "col11" "col1"
[15] "15"
```

I can't copy it like this and recreate a vector or modify it.

Comment: Try `dput(Vector)`

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.